# AVR, Using FIFO in interrupts

Tags: c++, timer, avr, fifo, interrupt-handling

Greetings to all connoisseurs. Good day.
I will try to program AVR ATMega328. I use the following libraries:
[bme280](https://github.com/maxmclau/bme280)
[avr-st7735](https://github.com/LongHairedHacker/avr-st7735)

Routine for Timer from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/qeewiki/books/avr-guide/timers-on-the-atmega328)

I want every two seconds to get the BME280 data, and I want to use TIMER1 and overflow, see code. I read the sensor as an interrupt handler. Use custom FIFO queue implementation. In the interrupt operation, the data is retrieved into the FIFO queue. Finally, I will try to read FIFO in the main loop.

Code:

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

extern "C" {
#include "spi.h"
#include "st7735.h"
#include "st7735_gfx.h"
#include "st7735_font.h"
#include "bme280/bme280.h"
#include <i2c/i2c_master.h>
#include "ftoa/ftoa.h"
}



#include <fifo.hpp>
#include "millis/millis.h"
#include "Utils/avr.hpp"


fifo_struct<float> fifo;

void showVisual()
{
    // Just toggle led diode state
}

// global variable to count the number of overflows
volatile uint8_t tot_overflow;

// initialize timer, interrupt and variable
void timer1_init()
{
// set up timer with prescaler = 8
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS11);
// initialize counter
    TCNT1 = 0;

// enable overflow interrupt
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1);

// initialize overflow counter variable
    tot_overflow = 0;
}



// TIMER1 overflow interrupt service routine
// called whenever TCNT1 overflows
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
// keep a track of number of overflows
    tot_overflow++;
// check for number of overflows here itself
// 61 overflows = 2 seconds delay (approx.)
    if (tot_overflow >= 61) // NOTE: '>=' used instead of '=='
    {
        {
            // Get data
            float data = 5.5f; //bme280_readTemperature();
            // Push to FIFO
            fifo_push<float>(&fifo, data); // TODO: Not in the effect! Why?
        }
        showVisual(); // blink with led

// no timer reset required here as the timer
// is reset every time it overflows
        tot_overflow = 0; // reset overflow counter
    }
}

extern "C" int main(void)
{
    // Init millis
    clock_init();

    // Init SPI and TFT
    spi_init();
    st7735_init();
    st7735_set_orientation(ST7735_LANDSCAPE_INV);
    st7735_fill_rect(0, 0, 128, 128, ST7735_COLOR_BLACK);

    // Initialize PWM 
    // Fast PWM with MAX
    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01) | (1 << WGM00);
    // Mode output
    // Noninvert for OC0A
    TCCR0A |= (1 << COM0A1);
    // Divider to 64
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00);
    // Set pwm to 200/255
    OCR0A = 200;


    // Initialize I2C and BME280 
    i2c_init();

    fifo = fifo_create<float>(5);
    if (!bme_init())
    {
        // Error!!
    }

    // initialize timer
    timer1_init();

    // Enable global interrupts
    sei();

    wdt_enable(WDTO_2S);

    while (1)
    {
        float val = fifo_pop<float>(&fifo);
        uart_puts(val); // Printed 0.0
        uart_puts(fifo_count<float>(&fifo)); // Allways print 0!

        wdt_reset();
    }
}
```

fifo.h

```
/**
 * This file is a part of FIFO implementation in C/C++
 * 
 * fifo.h
 *
 *  Created on: 14. 1. 2020
 *  Author:     Denis Colesnicov
 *  Licence:    WTFPL
 *  Version:    4
 */

#ifndef FIFO_HPP_
#define FIFO_HPP_

#include <stdint.h>


/**
 * Struktura udrzujici informace pro frontu
 */
template<typename T> struct fifo_struct
{
    volatile uint8_t top;   /*<! Ukazatel na vrchol zasobniku (na jakou pozici byl vlozen posledni prvek) */
    volatile T *data;       /*<! Pole s ulozenymi prvkz */
    uint8_t size;   /*<! Rezervovana velikost fronty */
};

/**
 * Vytvori novou frontu
 *
 * @note        Pro fifo_struct::data je pouzita f-ce calloc(...),
 *              musi se pouZit funkce free(..) pro uvolneni!
 * @param _size Kolik ma obsahovat prvku
 * @return      Vraci frontu
 */
template<typename T> fifo_struct<T> fifo_create(uint8_t _size);

/**
 * Kolik prvku je ve fronte
 *
 * @param _fifo Fronta
 * @return      Pocet prvku ve fronte
 */
template<typename T> uint8_t fifo_count(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo);

/**
 * Pro kolik prvku je rezervovana fronta (maximalni pocet prvku ve fronte)
 *
 * @param _fifo Fronta
 * @return      Pocet rezervovanych "mist"
 */
template<typename T> uint8_t fifo_size(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo);

/**
 * Odstrani z fronty vsechny ulozene prvky a vynuluje ji.
 *
 * @note        Frontu jiz nadale nebude mozne pouzivat!
 * @param _fifo Fronta
 */
template<typename T> void fifo_destroy(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo);

/**
 * Vlozi prvek na konec fronty
 *
 * @param _fifo Fronta
 * @param _data Data ke vlozeni
 */
template<typename T> void fifo_push(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo, T _data);

/**
 * Vrati data ktera jsou na zacatku fronty.
 *
 * @note        Data zustanou ve fronte (ne odstranuje ziskana data!)
 * @param _fifo Fronta
 * @return      Data
 */
template<typename T> T fifo_first(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo);

/**
 * Vrati data ktera jsou na konci fronty.
 *
 * @note        Data zustanou ve fronte (ne odstranuje ziskana data!)
 * @param _fifo Fronta
 * @return      Data
 */
template<typename T> T fifo_last(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo);

/**
 * Zredukuje velikost fronty o zadany pocet pozic
 * Posune obsah fronty do leva o zadany pocet pozic.
 * Data ktera byla na zacatku fronty budou odstranene!
 *
 * @param _fifo     Fronta
 * @param _count    Pocet pozic k posunu
 */
template<typename T> void fifo_reduce(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo, uint8_t _count);

/**
 * Vrati data ze zacatku fronty.
 *
 * @note        Tim dojde k odstraneni techto dat a zredukovani pole.
 *              @see fifo_reduce(...)
 * @param _fifo Fronta
 * @return      Data
 */
template<typename T> T fifo_pop(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo);

/**
 * Trida usnadnujici praci s FIFO frontou
 */
template<typename T>
class Fifo
{

public:

    /**
     * Vytvori novou frontu
     *
     * @param _size Kolik ma obsahovat prvku
     */
    Fifo(uint8_t _size);

    /**
     * Odstrani z fronty vsechny ulozene prvky a vynuluje ji.
     *
     * @note        Frontu jiz nadale nebude mozne pouzivat!
     * @param _fifo Fronta
     */
    ~Fifo();

    /**
     * Vrati data ktera jsou na zacatku fronty.
     *
     * @note        Data zustanou ve fronte (ne odstranuje ziskana data!)
     * @param _fifo Fronta
     * @return      Data
     */
    T first();

    /**
     * Vrati data ktera jsou na konci fronty.
     *
     * @note        Data zustanou ve fronte (ne odstranuje ziskana data!)
     * @param _fifo Fronta
     * @return      Data
     */
    T last();

    /**
     * Kolik prvku je ve fronte
     *
     * @return      Pocet prvku ve fronte
     */
    uint8_t count();

    /**
     * Pro kolik prvku je rezervovana fronta (maximalni pocet prvku ve fronte)
     *
     * @return      Pocet rezervovanych "mist"
     */
    uint8_t size();

    /**
     * Vrati data ze zacatku fronty.
     *
     * @note        Tim dojde k odstraneni techto dat a zredukovani pole.
     *              @see fifo_reduce(...)
     * @return      Data
     */
    T pop();

    /**
     * Vlozi prvek na konec fronty
     *
     * @param _fifo Fronta
     * @param _data Data ke vlozeni
     */
    void push(T _data);

    /**
     * Zredukuje velikost fronty o zadany pocet pozic
     * Posune obsah fronty do leva o zadany pocet pozic.
     * Data ktera byla na zacatku fronty budou odstranene!
     *
     * @param _count    Pocet pozic k posunu
     */
    void reduce(uint8_t _count);

private:

    fifo_struct<T> m_fifo; /*<! Fronta (FIFO) */
};


#include <stdlib.h>


template<typename T> fifo_struct<T> fifo_create(uint8_t _size)
{
    fifo_struct<T> fifo;
    fifo.top = 0;
    fifo.size = _size;
    fifo.data = (T*) calloc(_size, sizeof(T));
    return fifo;
}

template<typename T> uint8_t fifo_count(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo)
{
    return (uint8_t) _fifo->top;
}

template<typename T> uint8_t fifo_size(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo)
{
    return (uint8_t) _fifo->size;
}

template<typename T> void fifo_destroy(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo)
{
    _fifo->size = 0;
    _fifo->top = 0;
    free(_fifo->data);
}

template<typename T> void fifo_push(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo, T _data)
{
    if (_fifo->size == _fifo->top)
    {
        fifo_reduce<T>(_fifo, 1);
    }
    _fifo->data[_fifo->top] = _data;
    _fifo->top++;
}

template<typename T> T fifo_pop(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo)
{
    if (_fifo->top == 0)
    {
        return (T) NULL;
    }

    T data = _fifo->data[0];

    fifo_reduce<T>(_fifo, 1);
    return data;
}

template<typename T> T fifo_first(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo)
{
    if (_fifo->top == 0)
    {
        return (T) NULL;
    }
    return _fifo->data[0];
}

template<typename T> T fifo_last(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo)
{
    if (_fifo->top == 0)
    {
        return (T) NULL;
    }
    return _fifo->data[_fifo->top - 1];
}

template<typename T> void fifo_reduce(fifo_struct<T> *_fifo, uint8_t _count)
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < _fifo->size; i++)
    {
        _fifo->data[i] = _fifo->data[_count + i];
    }
    _fifo->top -= _count;
}

template<typename T>
Fifo<T>::Fifo(uint8_t _size)
{
    m_fifo = fifo_create<T>(_size);
}

template<typename T>
Fifo<T>::~Fifo()
{
    fifo_destroy<T>(&m_fifo);
}

template<typename T>
T Fifo<T>::first()
{
    fifo_first<T>(m_fifo);
}

template<typename T>
T Fifo<T>::last()
{
    fifo_last<T>(m_fifo);
}

template<typename T>
uint8_t Fifo<T>::count()
{
    return fifo_count<T>(m_fifo);
}

template<typename T>
uint8_t Fifo<T>::size()
{
    return fifo_size<T>(m_fifo);
}

template<typename T>
T Fifo<T>::pop()
{
    return fifo_pop<T>(&m_fifo);
}

template<typename T>
void Fifo<T>::push(T _data)
{
    fifo_push<T>(&m_fifo, _data);
}

template<typename T>
void Fifo<T>::reduce(uint8_t _count)
{
    fifo_reduce<T>(&m_fifo, _count);
}

#endif /* FIFO_HPP_ */
```

milli.h

```
/*
 * Project: Lightweight millisecond tracking library
 * Author: Zak Kemble, contact@zakkemble.net
 * Copyright: (C) 2018 by Zak Kemble
 * License: GNU GPL v3 (see License_GPL-3.0.txt) or MIT (see License_MIT.txt)
 * Web: http://blog.zakkemble.net/millisecond-tracking-library-for-avr/
 */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <util/atomic.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#include "millis.h"

#define CLOCK_SCALE_MICROS  0
#define CLOCK_SCALE_MILLIS  1
#define CLOCK_SCALE         CLOCK_SCALE_MICROS

#define MILLIS_TIMER0   0               /**< Use timer0. */
#define MILLIS_TIMER1   1               /**< Use timer1. */
#define MILLIS_TIMER2   2               /**< Use timer2. */
#define MILLIS_TIMER    MILLIS_TIMER0   /**< Which timer to use. */

#define MICROSECONDS_PER_TIMER0_OVERFLOW    16384
#define MILLIS_INC                          1024
#define FRACT_INC                           ((1024 % 1000) >> 3)
#define FRACT_MAX                           (1000 >> 3)

#ifndef F_CPU
#error "F_CPU not defined!"
#endif

#if F_CPU < 256 || F_CPU >= 32640000
#error "Bad F_CPU setting (<256 or >=32640000)"
#endif

#ifndef MILLIS_TIMER
#error "Bad MILLIS_TIMER set"
#endif

// Decide what what prescaler and registers to use
#if MILLIS_TIMER == MILLIS_TIMER0

// Timer0

#if F_CPU > 16320000 // 16.32MHz - 65.28MHz
#define CLOCKSEL (_BV(CS20))
#define PRESCALER 256
#elif F_CPU > 2040000 // 2.04MHz - 16.32MHz
#define CLOCKSEL (_BV(CS01)|_BV(CS00))
#define PRESCALER 64
#elif F_CPU > 255 // 256Hz - 2.04MHz
#define CLOCKSEL (_BV(CS01))
#define PRESCALER 8
#endif

#define REG_TCCRA       TCCR0A
#define REG_TCCRB       TCCR0B
#define REG_TIMSK       TIMSK0
#define REG_OCR         OCR0A
#define BIT_WGM         WGM01
#define BIT_OCIE        OCIE0A
#ifdef TIMER0_COMPA_vect
#define ISR_VECT        TIMER0_COMPA_vect
#else
#define ISR_VECT        TIM0_COMPA_vect
#endif
#define pwr_enable()    power_timer0_enable()
#define pwr_disable()   power_timer0_disable()

#define SET_TCCRA() (REG_TCCRA |= _BV(BIT_WGM))
#define SET_TCCRB() (REG_TCCRB |= CLOCKSEL)

#elif MILLIS_TIMER == MILLIS_TIMER1

// Timer1

// 1KHz - 65.28MHz
#define CLOCKSEL (_BV(CS10))
#define PRESCALER 1

#define REG_TCCRA       TCCR1A
#define REG_TCCRB       TCCR1B
#define REG_TIMSK       TIMSK1
#define REG_OCR         OCR1A
#define BIT_WGM         WGM12
#define BIT_OCIE        OCIE1A
#ifdef TIMER1_COMPA_vect
#define ISR_VECT        TIMER1_COMPA_vect
#else
#define ISR_VECT        TIM1_COMPA_vect
#endif
#define pwr_enable()    power_timer1_enable()
#define pwr_disable()   power_timer1_disable()

#define SET_TCCRA() (REG_TCCRA |= 0)
#define SET_TCCRB() (REG_TCCRB |= _BV(BIT_WGM)|CLOCKSEL)

#elif MILLIS_TIMER == MILLIS_TIMER2

// Timer2

#if F_CPU > 16320000 // 16.32MHz - 32.64MHz
#define CLOCKSEL (_BV(CS22)|_BV(CS20))
#define PRESCALER 128
#elif F_CPU > 8160000 // 8.16MHz - 16.32MHz
#define CLOCKSEL (_BV(CS22))
#define PRESCALER 64
#elif F_CPU > 2040000 // 2.04MHz - 8.16MHz
#define CLOCKSEL (_BV(CS21)|_BV(CS20))
#define PRESCALER 32
#elif F_CPU > 255 // 256Hz - 2.04MHz
#define CLOCKSEL (_BV(CS21))
#define PRESCALER 8
#endif

#define REG_TCCRA       TCCR2A
#define REG_TCCRB       TCCR2B
#define REG_TIMSK       TIMSK2
#define REG_OCR         OCR2A
#define BIT_WGM         WGM21
#define BIT_OCIE        OCIE2A
#define ISR_VECT        TIMER2_COMPA_vect
#define pwr_enable()    power_timer2_enable()
#define pwr_disable()   power_timer2_disable()

#define SET_TCCRA() (REG_TCCRA |= _BV(BIT_WGM))
#define SET_TCCRB() (REG_TCCRB |= CLOCKSEL)

#else
#error "Bad MILLIS_TIMER set"
#endif

static volatile millis_t timer_value;

// Initialise library
void clock_init()
{
    // Timer settings
    SET_TCCRA();
    SET_TCCRB();
    REG_TIMSK |= _BV(BIT_OCIE);
    REG_OCR = ((F_CPU / PRESCALER) / 1000);
}

// Get current timer_value
millis_t clock_get()
{
    millis_t ms;
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
    {
        ms = timer_value;
    }
    return ms;
}

// Turn on timer and resume time keeping
void clock_resume()
{
    pwr_enable();
    REG_TIMSK |= _BV(BIT_OCIE);
}

// Pause time keeping and turn off timer to save power
void clock_pause()
{
    REG_TIMSK &= ~_BV(BIT_OCIE);
    pwr_disable();
}

// Reset microseconds count to 0
void clock_reset()
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
    {
        timer_value = 0;
    }
}

// Add time
void clock_add(millis_t ms)
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
    {
        timer_value += ms;
    }
}

// Subtract time
void clock_subtract(millis_t ms)
{
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
    {
        timer_value -= ms;
    }
}


ISR(ISR_VECT)
{
    static unsigned char timer_fract = 0;

#if CLOCK_SCALE == CLOCK_SCALE_MICROS
    timer_value += MILLIS_INC;
    timer_fract += FRACT_INC;
    if (timer_fract >= FRACT_MAX)
    {
        timer_fract -= FRACT_MAX;
        timer_value += 1;
    }
#else
    timer_value += 1;
    timer_fract += 3;
    if (timer_fract >= 125)
    {
        timer_fract -= 125;
        timer_value += 1;
    }
#endif // CLOCK_SCALE
}
```

Problem: No data is stored in FIFO. Do you see someone solving please ??

Comment: Here has did i tested FIFO functionality: http://cpp.sh/5cnl4

Comment: In `fifo_push<float>(&fifo, data);` what is `fifo`? where it is declared? How do you know it is not in effect?

Comment: @AterLux Corrected.

Comment: I don't have debug tools, so I'm not sure if it's under effect. But I tried to meet the queue manually in the interrupt service but the advice it returns from the queue is empty. Unfortunately I can't Debug ..

Comment: sorry for bad english language..

Comment: There are many issues with the code. It is too complex. It has unnecessary array moving on each `fifo_push` and `fifo_pop` (why not a circular buffer?). FIFO methods are called from the main loop and from the interrupt but not are synchronized - so they do not work anyway. Also it is not clear what the issue do you have? Can you narrow down the problem and post the minimal code? You can duplicate the question in Russian on ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: at first glance is.  therefore it is not a class but a front.  therefore it is not circular.  I only remove elements from it when I need it.  Like QUEUE in FREERROS.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my strategy. My code already works differently. But my FIFO implementation could be useful to someone...